# Boost ICL map that replaces values in intervals?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-icl

[Boost.ICL](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html)'s `interval_map` has two kinds of behaviors: `+=` and `insert`. 
Both are useful in different context. 
The first adds up values in common intersections of two existing intervals. 
The second simply introduces the new value only in *previously unassigned* intervals (in previously assigned intervals the value is kept).

However I need a behavior that is subtly different, such that, in the example below instead of getting the undesired interval map `(1.,2.)->1 , (2.5,3.)->3, (3.,5.)->2` I get instead the desired `(1.,2.)->1 , (2.5,5.)->3`.

**That is, that new inserted values replace old values? 
How do I declare `interval_map` to get that *replacing* behavior?**

```
#include<boost/icl/interval_map.hpp>
int main(){
    boost::icl::interval_map<double, int> joined_map;
    joined_map.insert( std::make_pair(
        boost::icl::interval<double>::open(1., 2.),
        1
    ));
    joined_map.insert( std::make_pair(
        boost::icl::interval<double>::open(3., 5.),
        2
    ));
    joined_map.insert( std::make_pair(
        boost::icl::interval<double>::open(2.5, 5.),
        3
    )); // this line doesn't replace the old value 2, it keeps it.
}
```

Bonus: **Is that what `boost::icl::map` is supposed to do? How do I use it?**

---

**EDIT 1:** This is a more explicit and simplified sample code using C++11

```
#include<boost/icl/interval_map.hpp>
#include<iostream>

namespace icl = boost::icl;
using interval = icl::interval<double>;

int main(){
    icl::interval_map<double, int> joined_map;

    joined_map.insert({interval::open(1., 2.), 1});
    joined_map.insert({interval::open(3., 5.), 2});
    joined_map.insert({interval::open(2.5, 5.), 3}); 
    // ^^^^ this line doesn't replace the old value 2! it keeps it.
    for(auto e: joined_map) std::cout << e.first <<' '<< e.second <<'\n';
    // prints: (1,2) 1 \\ (2.5,3] 3 \\ (3,5) 2
    // desired: (1,2) 1 \\ (2.5,5] 3  // value 2 gone
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:** **Complete solution** based on @JorgeBellon's answer:

```
#include<boost/icl/interval_map.hpp>
#include<iostream>

namespace icl = boost::icl;

template <class Type>
struct inplace_replace{// : icl::identity_based_inplace_combine<Type>{
    using first_argument_type = Type;
    void operator()(Type& object, Type const& operand) const{object = operand;}
};

using interval = icl::interval<double>;

int main(){

    icl::interval_map<
        double, int,
        icl::partial_enricher,   // Unmapped intervals have unkown value;
                                 // store identity values
        std::less             ,  // Comparator
        inplace_replace     //,  // Combination operator // IMPORTANT!!
    //  icl::inplace_erasure//,  // Extraction operator
    //  closed_interval<unsigned, std::less> // Interval type
    > joined_map;
    joined_map.add({interval::open(1. , 2.), 1}); // or joined_map+=std::make_pair(...)
    joined_map.add({interval::open(3. , 5.), 2}); // IMPORTANT: USE add, NOT insert!!
    joined_map.add({interval::open(2.5, 5.), 3}); 
    // ^^^^ this line now replaces the old value 2
    for(auto e: joined_map) std::cout << e.first <<' '<< e.second <<'\n';
    // prints: (1,2) 1 \\ (2.5,5] 3  // value 2 gone
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the interval map's template parameters is the combination operator type.
The typical example consists on map using `std::set` or similar as a value and then it uses the *addition* or the *identity* (keep the existing value) as operations.

Since the *overwrite* example is not there by default, you can create yours and pass it to the map yourself:

```
#include <boost/icl/interval_map.hpp>

using namespace boost::icl;

// interval_map combiner functor: assigns new value if key exists
template <class Type>
struct inplace_replace : identity_based_inplace_combine<Type> {
  void operator()(Type &object, const Type &operand) const {
    object = operand;
  }
};

template<>
inline std::string unary_template_to_string<inplace_replace>::apply() {
  return "=";
}

// When adding, if interval exists, replaces value.
// When subtracting, if interval exists, removes value.
using ival_map =
    interval_map<unsigned,         // Key
                 unsigned,         // Value
                 partial_enricher, // Unmapped intervals have unkown value; store identity values
                 std::less,        // Comparator
                 inplace_replace,  // Combination operator
                 inplace_erasure,  // Extraction operator
                 >;
```

See complete example: https://ideone.com/C49bDM

Edit: deriving from `identity_based_inplace_combine<Type>` (`boost/icl/functors.hpp`) does the following:

- Defines `first_argument_type`, `second_argument_type` and `result_type`.
- It is used to create the `identity_element` value for that type (a static function). For example the identity value for a set is an empty set, for an integer it is `0` (useful when you do a sum), etc.

It is not mandatory to use it if your map is `partial_enricher` or `total_enricher`, since in this case the map will contain entries for any values, including identity values. You will need it for the `absorber` types, since the map needs to know whether it can drop the interval or not in that case.

An alternative:

```
// interval_map combiner functor: assigns new value if key exists
template <class Type>
struct inplace_replace {
  typedef void result_type;
  typedef Type& first_argument_type;
  typedef const Type& second_argument_type;

  void operator()(Type &object, const Type &operand) const {
    object = operand;
  }
};
```

Note: older boost ICL implementations derive from `std::binary_function` instead of using these typedefs. Unfortunately this is deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17, so I would try not to use it in your own code. The latest versions implement the functors like the snippet above.

Same example: https://ideone.com/lMLEDw

Comment: Is the derivation from `identity_based_inplace` necessary?

Comment: Excellent, this works. The problem to begin with is that I was trying to use `insert` and not `add`. Answering my own question, inheritance is not completely necessary if one has the right `typedef`. I put a complete solution in my question.

Comment: Deriving from `identity_based_inplace` is not necessary if you use `enricher` interval maps. It won't work if you want to use `absorber` maps because it needs to know what the identity of `Type` is, to be able to discard it.
More than anything, it is a convenience so that you don't need to define the argument types. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply erase the contents of the section you'r intending to overwrite before insertion:

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0625933bb8cb540)**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/icl/interval_map.hpp>

namespace icl = boost::icl;

int main()
{
    icl::interval_map<double, int> joined_map;
    using ival = icl::interval<double>;

    joined_map.add({ival::open(1., 2.), 1});
    joined_map.add({ival::open(3., 5.), 2});
    std::cout << "#1: "; for(auto el : joined_map) std::cout << el.first << ": " << el.second << ", "; std::cout << "\n";

    joined_map.erase(ival::open(3., 6.));
    joined_map.add({ival::open(3., 6.), 4});
    std::cout << "#2: "; for(auto el : joined_map) std::cout << el.first << ": " << el.second << ", "; std::cout << "\n";
}
```

This prints:

```
#1: (1,2): 1, (3,5): 2, 
#2: (1,2): 1, (3,6): 4,
```

Which I believe is what you wanted.

---

<sup>old answer text for <strike>comic relief</strike> future reference</sup>

I have a feeling the interval_map semantics aren't what you are expecting. I've played with this a little now, and can't say I do understand it, but I know enough to see that **there's not a simple 1:1 mapping** of things inserted and 'elements' stored in the container.

For this reason, many suprising deviations from std::map occur

- there's no `operator[]`, but `operator[]` is overloaded (returning `const`)
- `find()` returns a `const_iterator` (presumably because it can return a 'virtual node' that's somehow derived from the actual data). So you can't just expect to `map.erase(find(k))` - you have to explicitely erase by key or interval.
- there are `add` and `subtract` methods (aside from `insert`).

Demo code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/icl/interval_map.hpp>
#include <boost/icl/interval.hpp>

namespace icl = boost::icl;

int main()
{
    icl::interval_map<double, int,
       icl::partial_absorber,
       /*ICL_COMPARE Compare =*/ ICL_COMPARE_INSTANCE(ICL_COMPARE_DEFAULT, double), 
       /*ICL_COMBINE Combine =*/ ICL_COMBINE_INSTANCE(icl::inplace_plus, int), 
       /*ICL_SECTION Section =*/ ICL_SECTION_INSTANCE(icl::inter_section, int)
        > joined_map;
    using ival = icl::interval<double>;

    joined_map.add({ival::open(1., 2.), 1});
    joined_map.add({ival::open(3., 5.), 2});
    std::cout << "#1: "; for (auto el : joined_map) std::cout << el.first << ": " << el.second << ", "; std::cout << "\n";
    auto clone1 = joined_map;

    joined_map.add({3., 2});
    std::cout << "#2: "; for (auto el : joined_map) std::cout << el.first << ": " << el.second << ", "; std::cout << "\n";
    auto clone2 = joined_map;

    joined_map.add({3., 2});
    std::cout << "#3: "; for (auto el : joined_map) std::cout << el.first << ": " << el.second << ", "; std::cout << "\n";
    auto clone3 = joined_map;

    joined_map.add({ival::open(0., 6.), 10});
    std::cout << "#4: "; for (auto el : joined_map) std::cout << el.first << ": " << el.second << ", "; std::cout << "\n";
    auto clone4 = joined_map;

    for (double x = 0; x < 7; x += .5)
    {
        std::cout << x
            << "\t" << clone1(x)
            << "\t" << clone2(x)
            << "\t" << clone3(x)
            << "\t" << clone4(x) 
            << "\n";
    }
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19dd68d773a3a94d)**, prints:

```
#1: (1,2): 1, (3,5): 2, 
#2: (1,2): 1, [3,5): 2, 
#3: (1,2): 1, [3,3]: 4, (3,5): 2, 
#4: (0,1]: 10, (1,2): 11, [2,3): 10, [3,3]: 14, (3,5): 12, [5,6): 10, 
0   0   0   0   0
0.5 0   0   0   10
1   0   0   0   10
1.5 1   1   1   11
2   0   0   0   10
2.5 0   0   0   10
3   0   2   4   14
3.5 2   2   2   12
4   2   2   2   12
4.5 2   2   2   12
5   0   0   0   10
5.5 0   0   0   10
6   0   0   0   0
6.5 0   0   0   0
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually, my example was too restrictive (which allowed the solution with `std::map`). The idea is that new interval added will replace the old value, including when the added interval is larger. So if "insert" `{(2.5, 5.), 1}` to the map `(1.,2.)->1 (3.,5.)->3` I get the map `(1.,2.)->1 (2.5,5.)->1}`. I understand that by default it doesn't do it (which is inconsistent with my notion of map), but there must be a policy to does it.

Comment: I tried several and haven't noticed the behaviour you describe there. Maybe once, I'll have enough time to the the manual to YABL (Yet Another Boost Library)

Comment: I read the manual so many times. I love Boost, but some libraries are just strange! and some so strangely documented. Let alone that it takes days to realize that the library is not what you though it was for.

Comment: Just as I had decided to leave it, a thought crossed my mind: **edited** ^ (_I actually almost said it in my observations about `.erase()` :)_)